# Jquery Key/Value = Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to create an associative array for the first time and acces data with keys. My array builds fine but I am having a hard time figuring out how to get to the data. The console.log at the end returns undefined.

```
placesdata = [];

$.getJSON("php/data.php", function(data) {

    $.each(data.places, function(j,val){

        placesdata.push({

            placename: data.places[j].name,
            placedescription: data.places[j].notes,
            placelong: data.places[j].lon,
            placelat: data.places[j].lat,

        });

    });

    for(var i=0; i< placesdata.length; i++){
        console.log(placesdata[i][0]);
    }

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `[0]` from the `console.log` call.

Comment: That returns the whole record, sure. But I need to drill in one more level to get only placename. Is that wrong? Ideally I'd like to use placesdata[i][placename];

Comment: The array contains javascript objects, not arrays, so you would use `.placename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reference the pieces of the object within the array, so to print the placename:

```
for(var i=0; i< placesdata.length; i++){
    console.log(placesdata[i].placename);
}
```

you would do that for each of the attributes.